# Basic Rails Help (Iterating)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I basically want to only want this script to run for each show a user has to their name which is the model user_show. Here is what i have so far (below it is the part I am having trouble with).

```
class Show < ActiveRecord::Base
  require 'nokogiri'
  require 'open-uri'

  has_many :user_shows
  has_many :users, through: :user_shows



  def self.search(search)  
    if search  
      where('title LIKE ?', "%#{search}%")  
    else  
      scoped  
    end  
  end 

 def self.update_all_screenings
   UserShow.select(:show_id) do |show|
    show.update_attribute(:next_screening, Show.update_next_screening(Show.select(:url)))
  end

end

  def self.update_next_screening(url)
    nextep = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))
    ## Finds the title of the show and extracts the date of the show and converts to string ##
    begin

        title = nextep.at_css('h1').text
        date = nextep.at_css('.next_episode .highlight_date').text[/\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{4}/]
        date = date.to_s

    ## Because if it airs today it won't have a date rather a time this checks whether or not 
    ## there is a date. If there is it will remain, if not it will insert todays date
    ## plus get the time that the show is airing    
        if date =~ /\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{4}/
            showtime = DateTime.strptime(date, "%m/%d/%Y")
        else
            date = DateTime.now.strftime("%D")
            time = nextep.at_css('.next_episode .highlight_date').text[/\dPM|\dAM/]
            time = time.to_s
            showtime = date + " " + time
            showtime = DateTime.strptime(showtime, "%m/%d/%y %l%p")

        end

        return showtime

    rescue
        return nil
    end
  end
end
```

This is the part that isnt working

```
def self.update_all_screenings
       UserShow.select(:show_id) do |show|
        show.update_attribute(:next_screening, Show.update_next_screening(Show.select(:url)))
      end

    end
```

So basically I want it to go through each user_show, extract the show_id and then perform the script on that show.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have a `.each` before the do so it's not the correct syntax for the loop and because you're selecting the show_id from UserShow you're iterating over instances of UserShow not Show.

```
def self.update_all_screenings
  #get ids of unique shows belonging to users
  shows_with_users = UserShow.pluck("DISTINCT show_id")

  #get the Shows and loop
  Show.where(id: shows_with_users).each do |show|
    show.update_attribute(:next_screening, Show.update_next_screening(show.url))
  end
end
```

I assume you want that based on the rest of your code.  As I'm iterating over instances of show I can use show.url.  I don't get why you've made update next screening a class method though.

Comment: Hey I tried this and it almost works. It outputs this instead of acutally going through and getting the next screening for the app
`oad (0.0ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" IN (104821, 97083, 95768, 117257, 112683)
=> []`

Comment: I think that `User.where(id: shows_with_users).each do |show|` is meant to be `Show.where(id: shows_with_users).each do |show|`

Comment: Yeah, sorry put the wrong model in.  Thanks @MaxWilliams

Comment: This finally worked! Thanks heaps I have spent ages trying to figure this out getting no where.